# ASP.NET Core using custom authenticationhandler with cookieauthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create my own AuthenticationHandler and use with cookie authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MyAuth.Scheme;
  })
  .AddCookie()
  .AddScheme<MyAuthenticationOptions, MyAuthenticationHandler>(MyAuth.Scheme, "My auth scheme", options => { });
```

.

```
public MyAuthenticationHandler(...) : base(...) {}

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();  
    }    

    protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {                     
        var myUser = await DoAuth();

        if (!myUser.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("isRedirectedFromSSO"))
            {
                Context.Response.Redirect("/unauthorized");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Context.Response.Redirect("url to sso");
                return;
            }              
        }    

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Username),            
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, MyAuth.Scheme);
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties {};

        await Context.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            claimsPrincipal,
            authProperties);

        Context.Response.Redirect(Request.GetEncodedUrl());
    }
}
```

1. If there is a valid auth cookie, auth using that
2. If there is not a valid auth cookie, challenge using my auth and create an auth cookie if successful

This works in practice, but I find it a little weird I'm doing the actual authentication in `HandleChallenge` and redirecting if it fails.
It also seems odd to me to be calling one AuthenticationHandler (cookie) from another (MyAuthenticationHandler).

**How can I set this up correctly so that I'm doing the implementation in `HandleAuthenticate` instead?**
With my current implementation that method is never actually called.

Also, **is it ok to call one authentication handler from another?**

P.S. I have looked at several other posts and articles (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938511/asp-net-core-2-0-custom-middleware-using-cookie-authentication), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x) and [this](https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2)), but I have not been able to find the answers to my questions from looking at them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about chaining multiple middlewares?

Comment: How does one do that? Could you link to a basic example? :)

Comment: Who is your SSO Identity Provider?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the problem at first. Now I think I know what the problem is. Why you are doing this process in `HandleChallenge`, and not in `HandleAuthentication`?

Comment: That is my question precisely :)

Comment: @Win the SSO-provider is an internal service in my company

Comment: One day this link was very helpful for me, does this help you? If there is anything unclear here, I may also help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805411/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-middleware?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks, it has helped me alot to, but it doesn't explain how I can combine a custom auth handler with cookie authentication

Comment: @severin so the problem now is why is `HandleAuthentication` not being called? I am just trying to keep concentrated on the main problem or requisite of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're after may be solved with some new pieces in ASP.NET Core 2.1

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />`

Here's a sample of how to "select" auth schemes based on httpcontext data:

```
builder.AddPolicyScheme("scheme", "scheme", opts =>
{
    opts.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
    {
        if (ctx.Request.Query.ContainsKey("isRedirectedFromSSO"))
        {               
            return null; // or ctx.ForbidAsync(), not sure here.
        }

        return OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // or your own sso scheme, whatever it may be here.
    };
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect();
```

Have a look in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1559#issuecomment-387244674).

Comment: Check this link as well, was quite useful. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4648#issuecomment-410330370